# Finding equation of parabola

Tags: conic-sections

Find an equation of the parabola with focus at point $(0,5)$ whose directrix is the line $y=0$. (Derive this equation using the definition of the parabola as a set of points that are equidistant from the directrix and the focus)

Ok this one is killing me. My textbook has this

> An equation of the parabola with focus $(0,p)$ and directrix $y=-p$ is $x^2=4py$

However, my problem has $(0,p)$ with p being 5, yet the directrix is not $p=-y=-5$, it's $0$. And so I tried deriving it manually as they said by

$\sqrt{x^2+(y-p)^2}=|y+p|$

But that just takes me back to the original equation I mentioned, $x^2=4py$. Not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Edited to try to clarify OP's confusion:*

The distance between $(x,y)$ and $(0,5)$ is indeed $\sqrt{x^2+(y-5)^2}$.

The distance between $(x,y)$ and the line $y=0$ is $|y|$ (if $y>0$, then it is above the $X$-axis, and the distance is just the $y$ coordinate; if $y<0$, then the distance is $-y = |y|$). So the points on the parabola are exactly the points for which the two distances are equal, that is, all $(x,y)$ for which:
$$\sqrt{x^2+(y-5)^2} = |y|.$$
Now square both sides, and you'll get the equation of the parabola you want.

---

How is this related to the formula you quote? It's really all just the same process. If the directrix is either horizontal (a line of the form $y=k$) or vertical (a line of the form $x=\ell$), then it is very easy to compute the distance from a point to the directrix: the point $(x,y)$ is $|y-k|$ away from the line $y=k$, and is $|x-\ell|$ away from the line $x=\ell$. If the focus of the parabola is at $(a,b)$, then you want the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(a,b)$ to equal the distance to the directrix, so you get:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} &= |y-k| &\qquad&\mbox{if the directrix is $y=k$,}\\
\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} &= |x-\ell| &&\mbox{if the directrix is $x=\ell$.}
\end{align*}
Then squaring both sides yields the equation of the parabola. Doing it correctly will cancel out the $y^2$ term when the directrix is horizontal, and the $x^2$ term when the directrix is vertical.

For more general parabolas, when the directrix is neither horizontal nor vertical but an arbitrary line $y=mx+b$, you need to work a bit harder, because the distance from $y=mx+b$ to $(x,y)$ is not so simple to compute. Not *too* hard, but not as simple. Once you have a formula for the distance, you set it equal to the distance to the focus, square both sides, and get the equation of the parabola.

Comment: Ok so I get $x^2=2py-p^2$. However, I'm confused between whats p and whats y. Whenever we mentioned y so far, has it been about the same y, the one thats equal to 0? Because then we have the point (x,y)=(0,5) in which y=5, so thats confusing me a bit.

Comment: Ok wait I'm not making any sense. I just realized that p is just a general variable they're using. In our case, p=0, so wouldnt it just be $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=5$? But then thats a circle..

Comment: In Arturo Magidin's answer, $p=5$.  The $p$ in your question doesn't work here, because you need the directrix to be $y=-p$.  But, you have $y=0$ and $p=5$.

Comment: @f-Prime: I've rewritten, hopefully that will clarify.

Answer (score 3):

So, you have a method for writing an equation for a parabola where the focus is at $(0,p)$ and the directrix is $y=-p$, but now you want to write an equation for a parabola with focus $(0,5)$ and directrix $y=0$, which doesn't fit the formula.

If you take the conditions you are given and translate them down 2.5 units, the focus would be at $(0,2.5)$ and the directrix would be at $y=-2.5$, so you should be able to write an equation for that parabola.  Now, translate that equation up 2.5 units (replace $y$ with $(y-2.5)$).

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola):

Equation for a general parabola with a focus point $F =(u, v)$, and a directrix in the form

$$n_1x+n_2y+c=0 \,$$
is

$$\frac{\left|n_1x+n_2y+c\right|}{\sqrt{{n_1}^{2}+{n_2}^{2}}}=\sqrt{\left(x-u\right)^2+\left(y-v\right)^2} $$

So make the substitutions and verify that the what you get agrees with [Arturo Magidin's derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13569/finding-equation-of-parabola/13571#13571).